# Is my code mistaking a method as an attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing my Python homework using Spyder but it seems like the method dailyEffort is being mistaken as an object attribute by the code. Here is my code:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,ID,dept=None):
        self.name=name
        self.ID=ID
        if dept==None:
            self.dept="CSE"
        elif dept!=None:
            self.dept=dept
        self.sugg=""
        self.dE=0
        def dailyEffort(self,hour):    #Clearly this is a method
            self.hour=hour
            self.dE+=self.hour
            if self.hour<=2:
                self.sugg="Should give more effort!"
            elif self.hour<=4:
                self.sugg="Keep up the good work!"
            else:
                self.sugg="Excellent! Now motivate others."
        def printDetails(self):
            print("Name: ",self.name)
            print("ID: ",self.ID)
            print("Department: ",self.dept)
            print("Daily Effort: ",self.dE," hour(s)")    #I'm not even calling that method over here
            print("Suggestion: ",self.sugg)
bob = Student('Bob', 123)
bob.dailyEffort(3)    #This is where the code mistakes dailyEffort as an attribute
bob.printDetails()
print('========================')
alice = Student("Alice", 456, "BBA")
alice.dailyEffort(2)
alice.printDetails()
print('========================')
carol = Student("Carol", 777, "MAT")
carol.dailyEffort(6)
carol.printDetails()
```

Here is the output I'm getting:

```
runfile('C:/Users/USER/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/USER/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\USER\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 27, in <module>
    bob.dailyEffort(3)

AttributeError: 'Student' object has no attribute 'dailyEffort'
```

Here is the desired output:

```
Name: Bob
ID: 123
Department: CSE
Daily Effort: 3 hour(s)
Suggestion: Keep up the good work!
========================
Name: Alice
ID: 456
Department: BBA
Daily Effort: 2 hour(s)
Suggestion: Should give more effort!
========================
Name: Carol
ID: 777
Department: MAT
Daily Effort: 6 hour(s)
Suggestion: Excellent! Now motivate others.
```

Please suggest me as few changes as possible.

Comment: "#Clearly this is a method" - no it isn't, because of your indentation. Fix your indentation.

Comment: Also, methods *are* attributes.

Comment: Methods are attributes that contain functions.

Comment: You've indented the function too far. Its inside `__init__`. Dedent to the same level as `__init__` and it will become a class method instead of an inner function.

Comment: And `printDetails` has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is completely fine, just indentation error.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,ID,dept=None):
        self.name=name
        self.ID=ID
        if dept==None:
            self.dept="CSE"
        elif dept!=None:
            self.dept=dept
        self.sugg=""
        self.dE=0
    def dailyEffort(self,hour):    #Clearly this is a method
        self.hour=hour
        self.dE+=self.hour
        if self.hour<=2:
            self.sugg="Should give more effort!"
        elif self.hour<=4:
            self.sugg="Keep up the good work!"
        else:
            self.sugg="Excellent! Now motivate others."
    def printDetails(self):
        print("Name: ",self.name)
        print("ID: ",self.ID)
        print("Department: ",self.dept)
        print("Daily Effort: ",self.dE," hour(s)")    #I'm not even calling that method over here
        print("Suggestion: ",self.sugg)
bob = Student('Bob', 123)
bob.dailyEffort(3)    #This is where the code mistakes dailyEffort as an attribute
bob.printDetails()
print('========================')
alice = Student("Alice", 456, "BBA")
alice.dailyEffort(2)
alice.printDetails()
print('========================')
carol = Student("Carol", 777, "MAT")
carol.dailyEffort(6)
carol.printDetails()
```

**Actual Output :**

```
Name:  Bob                                                                                                                                            
ID:  123                                                                                                                                              
Department:  CSE                                                                                                                                      
Daily Effort:  3  hour(s)                                                                                                                             
Suggestion:  Keep up the good work!                                                                                                                   
========================                                                                                                                              
Name:  Alice                                                                                                                                          
ID:  456                                                                                                                                              
Department:  BBA                                                                                                                                      
Daily Effort:  2  hour(s)                                                                                                                             
Suggestion:  Should give more effort!                                                                                                                 
========================                                                                                                                              
Name:  Carol                                                                                                                                          
ID:  777                                                                                                                                              
Department:  MAT                                                                                                                                      
Daily Effort:  6  hour(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple indentation issue.

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self,name,ID,dept=None):
        self.name=name
        self.ID=ID
        if dept==None:
            self.dept="CSE"
        elif dept!=None:
            self.dept=dept
        self.sugg=""
        self.dE=0
        
    def dailyEffort(self,hour):    #Clearly this is a method
        self.hour=hour
        self.dE+=self.hour
        if self.hour<=2:
            self.sugg="Should give more effort!"
        elif self.hour<=4:
            self.sugg="Keep up the good work!"
        else:
            self.sugg="Excellent! Now motivate others."
    def printDetails(self):
        print("Name: ",self.name)
        print("ID: ",self.ID)
        print("Department: ",self.dept)
        print("Daily Effort: ",self.dE," hour(s)")    #I'm not even calling that method over here
        print("Suggestion: ",self.sugg)

        
bob = Student('Bob', 123)
bob.dailyEffort(3)    #This is where the code mistakes dailyEffort as an attribute
bob.printDetails()
print('========================')
alice = Student("Alice", 456, "BBA")
alice.dailyEffort(2)
alice.printDetails()
print('========================')
carol = Student("Carol", 777, "MAT")
carol.dailyEffort(6)
carol.printDetails()
```

Output:

```
Name:  Bob
ID:  123
Department:  CSE
Daily Effort:  3  hour(s)
Suggestion:  Keep up the good work!
========================
Name:  Alice
ID:  456
Department:  BBA
Daily Effort:  2  hour(s)
Suggestion:  Should give more effort!
========================
Name:  Carol
ID:  777
Department:  MAT
Daily Effort:  6  hour(s)
Suggestion:  Excellent! Now motivate others.
``
```

Answer (score 1):

`def` creates functions. If a function is defined at class scope and it is called on an instance of the class, python will treat it specially as a class method. If a function is created inside another function, it won't be a method, but if it uses variables in the containing function, it will be a closure.

In your case, `dailyEffort` is defined inside the `__init__` function but it doesn't use any containing variables, so its just a regular function object with the twist that its name is only known locally to the `__init__` function.

Dedent to the same level as `def __init__(...)` and it will work as a method.